# what is the use of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file in rhel?

Tags: linux, redhat, interface, udev

what is the use of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules file in linux?
is anyother way to change interface name in linux other than 70-persistent-net.rules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This file associates your NIC's MAC address with an interface name that will be given to the NIC at startup. There are certainly ways to change the name at runtime but if you reboot, it's gonna be the contents of that file that count.

Comment: Additionally, you can use it for renaming the interfaces.

Comment: marki: may i know the ways to change interface name ay runtime ?

Comment: I would change the interface name, stop the network service (on RHEL, service network stop), unload the kernel module for the network interface card (rmmod MOD_NAME), restart udev (on rhel, start_udev command), load the module and start the network service again. Please keep in mind that you will probably lose remote access to this server with this procedure.